# Code works with array, but not with csv-file in d3.js. Why?

Tags: csv, d3.js

I got a problem with using an csv-file in d3.js.

At first, I got my visualization by using an array with data:

var dataset = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4]

Depending on the number, there will be a different color for a rectangle. I did this by using the following lines of code:

```
.style("fill", function(d) {        
if      (d==1)  {return "black"}  
else if (d==2)  {return "red"} 
else if (d==3)  {return "yellow"} 
else if (d==4)  {return "green"} 
else            {return "purple"}             
;})
```

Because I want to make my code more flexible, I want to do the same using an csv-datafile. It looks like this:

```
2008
1
1
1
1
2
3
4
```

I included it with the following line of code:

```
d3.csv("landtag.csv", function(d) {
}
```

But, it doesn't work: All rectangle are purple, therefore the "else" was chosen.

The number of circles depends on the datalength - this is working!

Why is that possible? 
Do I insert the csv-file in the wrong way?

I tried already some solutions in tutorials, but none worked.

Thanks for your help!

---

My complete code:

```
// Width and height
    var w = 1000;
    var h = 1000;

    // create svg variable
    var svg = d3.select("p")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("id", "sitze") ;       

    var sitze; 

    d3.csv("landtag.csv", function(d) {


    // create variable
    var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(d["2008"])
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height", 50)

        //Bar width depending on number of datapoints in array 
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / d.length);  
            })

        // if for different colors
        .style("fill", function(d) {        
            if      (d=="1")    {return "black"}  
            else if (d=="2")    {return "red"} 
            else if (d=="3")    {return "yellow"} 
            else if (d=="4")    {return "green"} 
            else            {return "purple"}             
        ;}) 

        // paddings
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i % 17) * 55;}) 
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {return Math.floor(i / 17) * 55;});

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your CSV file are parsed as strings. This means that you don't get the number 1, but the string "1". If you change all your comparisons to strings (e.g. `(d=="1")`), it should work again. Alternatively, you can convert the strings into numbers before processing them, e.g. with this code.

```
csv.forEach(function(d) { return +d; });
```

Comment: I tried to use `d=="1"` , but it doesn't work. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Note that with the fragments you've posted, you may need d["2008"] to access the array of values. Can you post the complete code please?